# Optional Dependencies

Tags: angular

I am attempting to inject a dependency via @Inject() and wish it to be optional. The @Optional() tag doesn't seem to work with this type of dependency. The documentation on optional with @Inject states that it should be written @Inject(TOKEN, null); this however is not recognized as valid syntax. Is there any other way to allow undefined injections?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get access to it, are you sure you imported it?

```
import { Injectable, Optional } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService1 {
    constructor(@Optional() public testService2: TestService2) { }
}
```

> A parameter metadata that marks a dependency as optional. Injector
>   provides null if the dependency is not found.

https://angular.io/api/core/Optional

Comment: @Optional is for services, i'm injecting a token via a portal injector which may or may not this service defined depending on how it is created. I was able to find some additional information regarding this topic here -> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23849